# Do I have to individually center every element inside a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I have a `Grid` with 6 buttons arranged in 3 columns and 2 rows. I want each button to be centered in its own cell. The following code accomplishes it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
</Grid>
```

But I'm repeating myself a lot. Is there any way to say "Everything within this `Grid` is `Center`ed"?

Comment: why cant to create style for grid ....and apply style or create controltemplate with sytle

Comment: @PranayRana - You took the words out of my mouth. That is the best way to do it. You can create a template once and then all the buttons can inherit it without any extra code.

Comment: it should be centered by default

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Fine, then, bottom aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to achieve this for all control, but to answer your specific query, try setting a style for you buttons within the grid...

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: Good enough! Any way to specify, e.g. both `Button` and `TextBlock` in one go?

Comment: @Superbest, you can try to set it for all `Control`s (but this will affect all other controls).